# Creating variables dependent on one another, with repeating sets of integers; error in 'rep' function

Tags: r, function, variables, integer, repeat

First, I produced a set of integers (from 1 to 30) of random length, which reproduces 360 times.

```
x <- unlist(replicate(360, 1:sample(30, 1)))
```

So far I have this, but I get error messages and I don't even think it's entirely logically sound:

```
x <- x # x repeats 360 times 
y <- rep( 1:3, times = x )  # y repeats x times
z <- rep( 1:120, times = x )  # z repeats x times
```

My next step is to compute variables based on the list above. 
I want to get something like this:

```
x: 1 2 3 4 5  
y: 1 1 1 1 1 (number 1 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
z: 1 1 1 1 1 (number 1 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16  
y: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (number 2 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
z: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (number 1 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13  
y: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 (number 3 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
z: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (number 1 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20  
y: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 (here we repeat number 1 again, as 
the ‘y’ variable restarted)
z: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (variable ‘y’ restarted, so 
variable ‘z’ moves on to number 2 for the length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2 3  
y: 2 2 2 (number 2 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
z: 2 2 2 (number 2 repeats for the length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24  
y: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 (number 3 repeats for the 
length of ‘x’)
z: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 (number 1 repeats for the 
length of ‘x’)
x: 1 2  
y: 1 1 (here variable ‘y’ restarts again, we repeat number ‘1’ for the length 
of x)
z: 3 3 (since ‘y’ restarted, ‘z’ moves on to 3)
```

etc. until ‘z’ reaches 120, within which ‘y’ has gone through 1-3

Comment: I tried both answers and both work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to have a single matrix with variables x,y,z, this should do the job:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- replicate(360, 1:sample(30, 1))
# the length of each sample
len_x = sapply(x, length)

y = rep(1:3, 360/3)
# repeating each of 1,2,3 len_x times 
y_xtimes = rep(y, len_x) 

# len_z creates the sum of how many times y = 1,2,3 is repeated each time
len_z = rowSums(matrix(len_x, nrow = 120, byrow = TRUE))
z_xtimes <- rep(1:120, len_z)

DF <- cbind(x = unlist(x), y = y_xtimes, z = z_xtimes)
```

Comment: I have a follow-up question, I hope the solution is not too obvious! 

I need to create one more variable, essentially the same as variable z, except that instead of repeating numbers from 1 to 120, I need to have random numbers from 40 to 200 repeated, something like: 
    160 160 160 160 160 160 91 91 91 87 87 172 172 172 etc.

Comment: add  `new_var =  rep(sample(40:200, 120, replace = TRUE), len_z)`

Comment: if you want to add this variable to the final DF, just run: `DF <- cbind(x = unlist(x), y = y_xtimes, z = z_xtimes, d = new_var)`

Answer (score 0):

Let's first start by creating the random samples:

```
x <- replicate(360, 1:sample(30, 1)) # create the 360 samples
```

Now we can create the desired y with `lapply` as follows (I used the index of x to determine whether y should be 1, 2 or 3:

```
y <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) rep(((i - 1) %% 3) + 1, length(x[[i]])))
```

The same can be done for z, with a slightly different function to obtain the desired value of z (ranging from 1 to 120 depending on index of x) .

```
z <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) rep((i + 2) %/% 3, length(x[[i]])))
```

Depending of the desired structure of your output, you can then `unlist` them and/or combine them together in a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(x = unlist(x), y = unlist(y), z = unlist(z))
```